# Is a new Array created when varargs is used?

Tags: java, arrays, immutability

Consider the following class:

```
class Collection {

    private Object[] terms;
    public Collection(Object... terms) {
        this.terms = terms;
    }

    // Do something with terms...
}
```

I am trying to maintain immutability with this class, and I would like to know a little more about varargs and it's functionality. When I use arguments:

```
Collection c = new Collection(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

I would assume a new array is created in the above instance. However, if I were to do something like the below code:

```
Object[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4};
Collection c = new Collection(arr);
```

Is a new array implicitly created in the above instance due to the use of varargs, or is the array simply passed by reference just like if the type argument was for an `Object[]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say no because of the following.  The original array is used.  A new one is not created.

```java
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int[] v = { 1, 2, 3, 4
      };
      System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(v));
      test(v);
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(v));
   }

   public static void test(int... vals) {
      System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(vals));
      vals[2] = 1000;
   }
```

Prints out

```
2085857771
2085857771
[1, 2, 1000, 4]
```

Comment: The literal answer to the question would be that indeed new array is created when *varargs* is used. But as demonstrated by this answer, a method can not rely on the assumption that the caller used the *varargs* feature.

Comment: @Holger  I always knew that the target of a varargs type was an array.  And that if one passed individual values to that type, they would be placed in an array which had to come from somewhere.  I interpreted the question to mean something like *other than the expected array* which might require some strange, inefficient copying function.  I presume when you pass an explicit array the compiler says, *hey cool!  Less work for me to do.*  And I haven't checked the JLS but I wonder if this is implementation specific.

Comment: Sure, you answered the question as intended (and got my upvote for that). I just wanted to point at the terminology, as used in the question’s title. You perform a *varargs* call when you pass `int` values to a method declared as `test(int... vals)` and that will always create a new temporary array. In contrast, when you invoke the same method with an `int[]` array, you are not making a *varargs* call, but just invoke a method taking an array. In other words, `Array.asList(…)` works as before Java 5 when passing an array, returning a wrapper which allows modifications to the original array.

Answer (score 0):

As I interpret the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.2) no new Array is created, if you pass one array as an argument. The example of WJS also demonstrates, that it stays the same array in this case, since changes made in the vararg-function are still visible after its execution.